# Updating entity including lazy loaded child with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this model

```
public class CPAppModel
{
    [Key]
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual CPAppCategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

and i use the following code to Add/Update entries

```
 var db = new CheckpointApplicationContext();
                if (int.Parse(AppModel.AppId) == 0) return;
                if (!db.AppExist(AppModel))
                {
                    db.Applications.Add(AppModel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Message = "Record Added!";
                }
                else
                {
                    var existingEntry = db.Applications.First(a => a.AppId == AppModel.AppId);

                    existingEntry.AppDescription = AppModel.AppDescription;
                    existingEntry.AppName = AppModel.AppName;
                    existingEntry.Category = AppModel.Category;                  
                    existingEntry.Tags = AppModel.Tags;
                    existingEntry.AppDescription = AppModel.AppDescription;

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Message = "Record Updated!";

                }
```

the problem is in the Category update.

The scenario is - I might be getting a new category for my entity or a different (existing Category).
I thought that when using lazy loading, it would update it "magically" all by itself - this is not the case.
I', getting a primary key error.

Is there an easier way of achieving Add/Update logic for my "Entire Entity"

- Attach has not worked for me
- AddObject is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had forgotten to add the categories as a dbset
once I had that - attach started working.

```
            db.Categories.Attach(AppModel.Category);
            db.Applications.Attach(AppModel);                               

            db.SaveChanges();
```